# Python process not responding

Tags: python, nginx, tornado, reportlab, supervisord

For a web project we are running 5 python processes. When we assigned a huge CPU-intensive task to one of the processes, cpu usage of that process reached to 100%. Then gradually one by one, all of the 5 processes reached to cpu usage 100% and eventually all became non-responsive! My question is, **how does a heavy task to one process affect other processes?**

This is the big picture, complete scenario in details:

We are using **[Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)** web server. We are running 5 Tornado process (managed by [**supervisor**](http://supervisord.org/)). We have [**nginx**](http://nginx.org/en/) in front of all of the 5 tornado processes for load-balancing in round robing order. I.e. first web request will be sent to first Tornado process, second web request will be sent to the second Tornado process and so on.

Now, we have a huge PDF generation task (which uses [**ReportLab**](http://www.reportlab.com/) 3). We make a request from the server, and nginx passes it to a Tornado process. The process usage (seen via `top` command) becomes 100%. Then gradually one after another, all process usage become 100%, screen-shot follows:

[image: Screenshot of all processes becoming 100%]

And no other web request are being processed anymore.

My question is, why cpu intensive task in one python process hampers other python processes? We are using **python 3**.

Comment: I see rabbitmq also; so the process is - nginx > tornado > rabbitmq > task runner?

Comment: We have some tasks running by celery with rabbitmq backend, but this particular task does not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: Your setup is such that the supervisor or nginx thinks that the Python process is unusable and automatically sends the same request to the next Python process. Or, the user clicks "reload" in the browser or whatever.

Perhaps you should modify your Python processes to log what they are about to do (log *before* the long task, not afterwards). That way you could check if my guess is right.

Comment: We have a test setup, where no requests are being made while we run the heavy task. The log output halts before entering the task and stays there.